# PHP resize and crop centered-top image

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I'm trying to resize (keeping the aspect ratio) and crop the excess of image (outside the thumbnail limits), but doing that while crop x = center and y = top.

I'm missing something here, but my final image fits inside the thumbnail area, and not fill it and crop the excess. Hope someone can help me on this.

This is my code, so far:

```
$image_width = 725; // not static, just an example
$image_height = 409; // not static, just an example

// image can be wide or portrait

$width = 140;
$height = 160;

$thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
$white = imagecolorallocate($thumbnail, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($thumbnail, 0, 0, $white);        

$width_ratio = $image_width/$width;
$height_ratio = $image_height/$height;

if ($width_ratio>$height_ratio) {
    $dest_width=$width;
    $dest_height=$image_height/$width_ratio;        
}
else{       
    $dest_width=$image_width/$height_ratio;
    $dest_height=$height;           
}   

$int_width = ($width - $dest_width)/2;
$int_height = ($height - $dest_height)/2;        

imagecopyresampled($thumbnail, $original_image, $int_width, $int_height, 0, 0, $dest_width, $dest_height, $image_width, $image_height);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$image_width`, `$image_height`, `$width` and `$height` are static, which means `$width_ratio` and `$height_ratio` are always they same aswell (respectively: `5.1785714285714` and `2.55625`, so width ratio is always higher then height ratio).

In this case, this block of your code:

```
if ($width_ratio>$height_ratio) {
    $dest_width=$width;
    $dest_height=$image_height/$width_ratio;        
}
else{       
    $dest_width=$image_width/$height_ratio;
    $dest_height=$height;           
}
```

will always run `if` and never run `else` - remove it and leave just:

```
$dest_width=$image_width/$height_ratio;
$dest_height=$height;
```

and your image will be cropped based on higher value - in this case height will be resized accordingly to new height and excess of width will be cut off.

Hope this is what you were looking for!

**EDIT:**

Right now script if cutting off edges equally. If you want them to be cut fully from top or left (depends on ratio), then:

Remove that part of code totally:

```
$int_width = ($width - $dest_width)/2;
$int_height = ($height - $dest_height)/2;
```

Change your `if` `else` condition mentioned before to:

```
if($width_ratio < $height_ratio) {
    $dest_width=$width;
    $dest_height=$image_height/$width_ratio;

    $int_width = ($width - $dest_width)/2;
    $int_height = 0;
} else {       
    $dest_width=$image_width/$height_ratio;
    $dest_height=$height;

    $int_width = 0;
    $int_height = ($height - $dest_height)/2;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Horizontal always cut off equally, vertical always from the top - as you wanted:

```
if($width_ratio < $height_ratio) {
    $dest_width=$width;
    $dest_height=$image_height/$width_ratio;
} else {       
    $dest_width=$image_width/$height_ratio;
    $dest_height=$height;
}

$int_width = ($width - $dest_width)/2;
$int_height = 0;
```

Comment: Prajsnar the original image size is not fixed, that was only an example. My bad for not saying it. Althou doing what you said, it worked for horizontal image, but what about vertical images?

Comment: Just change your `>` to `<` in `if` condition, that should do it. (The condition i mentioned before)

Comment: Prajsnar It worked! The only thing now that i'm missing is the crop always start from top (i though 0 would do).. and not center verticaly..

Comment: Well, not really. Imagine it like this: your image is being resized down (keeping ratio) until it "fits" your 140x160 frame either by width or height. Now, if it first fits by height, then excess of width if being cut off **equally** from both sides (and it works correctly here), but you have nothing more to cut or move from top and bottom, cause with these values image fits perfectly. Same thing if it first fits by width - top and bottom are being cut off equally and there is nothing more to cut on the sides.

Comment: Or maybe if misunderstand it... you **want** crop to always start from top / left (cause it isn't now) or you **want** cropping equally from both longer sides (as it is now)?

Comment: Updated my answer in case you wanted image to be cut off always fully from top / left (depends on ratio) and not equally from sides - let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Prajsnar the idea is to crop central on X, while keeping Y on top. In other words, crop left-right and/or bottom if image is portrait and the excess exists in vertical. I dont mind if needed to separate the functions for wide and for portrait..

Comment: Ok, so you just put `$int_width = ($width - $dest_width)/2;` and `$int_height = 0;` after the `if` `else` - i updated my answer.